# What project design tools are available?

Tags: arduino-uno, project

What do you guys use for project designing?

I just found out about AutoDesk's 123D Circuits, which is nice but I wonder if there is something with more components, tools, etc?

For example, I can add an accelerometer to my project there but no signs of a LCD. I have been learning hardware recently and I feel there should be more complete tools out there.

I know this question may be opinion based but I could not find anywhere to ask. Thanks,

Comment: If the tool you're using doesn't allow you to create custom parts then, as they say, drop it like it's hot.

Comment: ok but do you suggest something? What do you use?

Comment: I currently use EAGLE, but I'll probably be jumping to CircuitMaker once it reaches open beta.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1222/what-are-low-cost-circuit-and-pcb-design-software/1228#1228

Answer (score 2):

I am using KiCad. It's a full EDA/PCB design suite that is **free**. It's a really nice multi-platform package. It doesn't do circuit simulation(to my knowledge). It's relatively easy to learn via some youtube tutorials and there's a healthy development community and discussion board as well. It outputs industry standard gerber files so you can quote out your designs to pcb manufacturers.

link:
http://www.kicad.org/

Comment: I use this and am fond of it

Answer (score 1):

I think [Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/home/) is used quite a lot. I have used it myself a couple of times, and I felt it was quite comprehensive. But I haven't used it enough to say whether this is *the* tool to choose.

Comment: Fritzing is actually very basic once you go beyond the breadboard.

Answer (score 1):

So, as the other users said, tou can use FRITZING, it is totally free and it does have LCD and a lot of other Shields. But the thing is, if you want a more complete design tool, PROTEUS 8.1 is a very used tool and by far more easy to use than any other design tool (as a complete designer solution). You can even simulate your lcd in software to test if everything is ok before start mounting your Circuit.

Proteus Site: http://www.labcenter.com/index.cfm

Proteus is not free but you can use a lot it.

Here's some images of arduinos in Proteus (The site in portuguese but you just need to see the pictures): 
http://microcontrolandos.blogspot.com.br/2013/04/proteus-8-professional.html

Answer (score 0):

I use [ExpressSCH](http://www.expresspcb.com/) for doing schematics, usually for posting on web sites like this. It is free, runs on Windows only, and is simple enough to use that I picked it up quite quickly. :)

Example schematic:

[image: ExpressSCH example]

The red arrows I added later in the GIMP.

It comes with quite a few symbols pre-defined. You can make others from scratch (using boxes, lines, etc.) or take an existing one, "break it apart", and then re-assemble to your desires. Once you have something the way you want it you "group as symbol" and it can be used again in the future.

The program has a sister program ExpressPCB for PCB layouts, however I haven't used that much.